# How can I make the c++ fstream class references compile in Visual Studio 2010 CLR

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, developer-tools

In the following code, Visual Studio 2010 C++ does not recognize accepts the fstream include but does not recognize the fstream type:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

class Test_CLR
{
    int openFlag;

    int isOpen(void)
    {
        return openFlag;
    };

    fstream testFile;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

fstream is in the std namespace. Try std::fstream instead. For more information see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/

Furthermore, you can allow usage of a type in different scopes with the 'using' keyword, for more information on that see http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/namespaces.html

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting to specify the namespace ( you can find more info on namespaces here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/ )

Essentially you can make the fstream class use the std namespace in three ways:

**Approach 1**

Declare your entire file to use the std namespace:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;   //ADDED CODE

class Test_CLR
{
    int openFlag;

    int isOpen(void)
    {
        return openFlag;
    };

    fstream testFile;
};
```

**Approach 2**

Declare you entire program to use only **fstream** from the std namespace:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

using std::fstream;   //ADDED CODE

class Test_CLR
{
    int openFlag;

    int isOpen(void)
    {
        return openFlag;
    };

    fstream testFile;
};
```

**Approach 3**

Declare a single use of fstream to be linked to the std namespace:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

class Test_CLR
{
    int openFlag;

    int isOpen(void)
    {
        return openFlag;
    };

    std::fstream testFile;   //ADDED CODE
};
```

The differences are explained in the link posted at the top. Take your pick :)